# iterate items of radio-button

Tags: angular, typescript

how can I show *items* of **radio buttons**, knowing that the values of these items are consumed from backend api.

```
        <div class="input-group col-md-9   input-group-sm">
             <label>gender</label>
        </div>

        <!-- TO CORRECT

  <div class="row full-name-inputs">
      <div class="input-group col-md-4   input-group-sm">
      <input type="radio" name="gender" [(ngModel)]="developer.gender" class="form-control" >
       </div>
  </div>

       -->
```

**TS**

```
 genders: GenderModel[];

  ngOnInit() {   


      this.developerService.getAllGender().subscribe(
        data=>{ this.genders= data; },
        error=>{console.log("error");})
```

Comment: Can you show the response from your api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the response from you api on a table and loop this table on your html.I have no idea how is the response from your api but look an example:

TS

```
genders: GenderModel[];

ngOnInit() {
this.developerService.getAllGender().subscribe(
    data=>{ this.genders= data; },
    error=>{console.log("error");})
}
```

Html

```
<div *ngFor="let gen of genders">
 <label for="{{gen}}">
   <input id="{{gen}}" [value]='gen' type="radio" name="genders" 
     [(ngModel)]="developer.gender" class="form-control" >
     {{gen}}
 </label>
```

Live [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f4i5c2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Ofcourse! radio.namefromResponse is for example! I have no idea how look likes your api response.If you post it on your question we will be able to help you

Comment: I know it was an example !! I've already changed the variables. I'll post it right now

Comment: I show your updated post. This data on your response is just a table?male female?

Comment: Can you post a reponse example?

Comment: what do you mean by reponse example ?

Comment: It's object with many levels? or just {'male', 'female',etc...}.If it's simple array just change on ngfor loop input to name="radio". I update my answer

Comment: @titi now working!Check my answer! i added a live example. Just add your bootstrap classes

Comment: it didn't work for me because I forgot **@CrossOrigin** annotation in the backend now it works but with pre-selected value I can'r change it

Comment: @titi can you upvote the answer for the time i spent to help you?